What are "Platt Skeet" and "Whoof, whoof"?
In Agatha Christie's The Man in the Brown Suit (freely/legally available to read online), one excerpt from Eustace Pedler's diaries describes his experience at the the Legislative Assembly of South Africa in Cape Town, where he listens to a speech in a language which is described as Dutch (perhaps today it would be called Afrikaans?):

He dropped out his words one by one in a particularly melancholy fashion. Every now and then he galvanized himself to further efforts by ejaculating something that sounded like “Platt Skeet,” uttered fortissimo and in marked contrast to the rest of his delivery. When he did this, half his audience yelled “Whoof, whoof!” which is possibly Dutch for “Hear, hear,” and the other half woke up with a start from the pleasant nap they had been having. I was given to understand that the gentleman had been speaking for at least three days. They must have a lot of patience in South Africa.

Not speaking Dutch/Afrikaans myself, I wasn't able to figure out the meaning of "Platt Skeet" or "Whoof, whoof!", as presumably these are not the proper spellings of the words being referred to, but rather an anglicisation indicating the character's lack of regard for the language. What do these mean?

I think the passage illustrates how Sir Eustace Pedler looks down on people who speak Afrikaans. Afrikaans was already a separate language from Dutch at the time when Agatha Christie published the novel in 1924. In fact, in 1925, the South African government recognised Afrikaans as a distinct language.
Pedler's description of the members of the Legislative Assembly's behaviour is suspicious enough on its own: "a three days’ speech", interrupting the speech with sudden shouts, the audience yelling back, others waking up "with a start from the pleasant nap". Looking at the individual words reinforces the impression that Pedler is just ridiculing them:

“skeet” sounds like skiet, an Afrikaans verb meaning "to shoot" that is derived from Dutch schieten.
“Platt” sounds most like the Afrikaans noun platt, meaning "leaf" or "sheet". (See also Dutch blad.) The combination with "skiet" is nonsensical.
“Whoof, whoof!” corresponds with the Afrikaans onomatopoeia "woef woef" for the barking of a dog. (See the Afrikaans Wikipedia article Onomatopee. Dutch uses the same onomatopoeia.)

Whatever members of the Legislative Assembly would shout in response to a particular point in a speech is unlikely to sound like the barking of a dog. Imagine a Persian visitor to the House of Commons claiming that a speaker in the House interrupted his speech by shouting "Leaf shoot!" and that other members yelled back, "Woof woof!"

P.S. I am a native speaker of Dutch.

In fairness, members of the British House of Commons do often make animal noises in lieu of proper discourse, and those in the House of Lords may nap during speeches :-) I wondered if "whoof, whoof" might have been something like "hear, hear", and hoped "platt skeet" would have been (when properly written/understood) something meaningful too. But of course, Pedler's ignorant upper-class Britishness was clear from the beginning, with all the snobbery that colonialism implies.

Tsundoku, we say 'woof woof' in English too (not 'bark bark'), though some people render the sound as 'ruff ruff'.

@KateBunting Who is we?

Speakers of English!

@KateBunting What I meant is that barking is sometimes also rendered as "Bark bark" and not always is "woof woof".

I don't remember hearing it in 70+ years!

@Randal'Thor My English-Dutch dictionary translates "Hear hear!" as "Bravo!", which sounds very different from "Whoof whoof" and does not involved repetition. I don't know whether there is a corresponding phrase in Afrikaans that involves repetition.

@Tsundoku The comic strip that you linked is, well, a comic strip, in which a noisy activity may be indicated either by a verb for that activity or by an onomatopoeic interjection. A dog barks, so the process of it doing so might be shown in a comic strip by "[bark] [bark]", but the sound itself would be "woof woof". Similarly, a cow lows but its sound is "moo", a sheep bleats but its sound is "baa", etc. See e.g. Wiktionary listing woof as an interjection but bark as a noun/verb.
